# How to improve Xcode's build time

Tags: swift, build, xcode6, xcode6.1

My project is getting fairly large and Xcode is taking ages to build. I've tried using a RAM disk but that didn't improve my build time noticeably.

The RAM disk I added:

```
hdid -nomount ram://4194304
newfs_hfs -v DerivedData /dev/rdiskN
diskutil mount -mountPoint ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData /dev/diskN
```

Where N is the Disk number.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can improve my build time?
At the moment the build time is anything from 30s to 120s. Perhaps not that long but it still bothers me. Sometimes I just want to make small tweaks and quickly check the result. The .swift file's I am editing are around 400 lines of code each.

Comment: How about splitting it up into libraries?